# Can you move a Service fabric cluster to another subnet?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network

We have a service fabric cluster that runs in a 10.0.0.0/24 inside a 10.0.0.0/8 VNET. Our customer wants to join this via VPN to their own network. However the there are conflict issues with the ip range we are using and the range that our customer wants us to use (10.90.15.0/24, size is no issue).

We tried creating a new subnet 10.90.15.0/24 however when we edited the subnet reference for the underlying virtual machine scale set to this new subnet the cluster refuses to start and in the event viewer this can be seen:

```
Throwing coding error - Seed node '35ee85474352dcc2e88fa9ad6af912b1' with address 
'10.90.15.4:1025' mismatches configured address '10.0.0.4:1025' 
Symbol paths: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;;
Symbol loading time: 00.161
Stack trace:
    00007ff7:25f5478c( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25f06592( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25f06413( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:26186be7( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:2616ef25( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25eaceeb( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25eb7471( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25eba4f9( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25ed5090( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25ec7c25( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25ec7c84( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25f37de8( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25eae132( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25ec617a( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25ea7a5a( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25eab10a( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    00007ff7:25f07607( windows_error(487): Attempt to access invalid address.  )
    RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive + 0x445e
    RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive + 0x2674
    BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x14
```

Now whilst I understand that the configuration of the cluster hasn't changed but the IP has I am somewhat stumped when it comes to a solution. Could it be that moving subnet is impossible without reinstalling the virtual machine scale set extension for service fabric and that it means a full recreation of the cluster and restoring the back-ups. Which by all means is possible but undesirable.

Is there someone that has done this or who perhaps has a completely different idea how this can be accomplished?

Edit: Due to illness I haven't been able to test what has been suggested, will do that as soon as possible.

Edit 2: `nicPrefixOverride` was already changed as a part of ARM-script, so that doesn't seem to make a difference that the setting was changed.

Comment: What happens when you redeploy the extension with a different `nicPrefixOverride`?

Comment: If you have a look at the SF directory on the nodes, you will discover they have ip references to the other cluster members. Simply switching the vmss subnet won't update these references, so the cluster won't know how to communicate anymore. For these sorts of changes, its always cleaner to just deploy a new cluster and move the workloads over.

Comment: After doing some thinking I believe that @CodedBeard suggestions is a better way to go about it. For my part you can make a post so I can label it as answered if you want.

However isn't extending the cluster with a secondary scale set in the correct subnet and then migrating the workloads and state would be preferable to creating a fully new cluster and migrating or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the SF directory on the nodes, you will discover they have ip references to the other cluster members. Simply switching the vmss subnet won't update these references, so the cluster won't know how to communicate anymore. For these sorts of changes, its always cleaner to just deploy a new cluster and move the workloads over.

While yes, adding a new vmss in the correct subnet may well work, in my own experiance, I've found it to be more consistently succefull to start from scratch. Plus, I've previously had a cluster bricked by an Azure update, so having experiance reprovisioning a cluster in this situation was really helpful rather than having to try it for the first time during an outage.